# jquery datetimepicker array of times per date

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Im looking to get the jquery datetimepicker to display different array of available times specific per date.  I have the datetimepicker displaying my available dates just fine with some allowed times:

```
var array = ["2015-10-23","2015-10-24","2015-10-25"];
$('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    startDate:  '2015/10/23',
    allowTimes:['17:00','17:30','18:00','18:30'],
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date ), array) > -1)
    {
        return [true,"","available"];
    }
    else
    {
        return [false,'',"booked"];
    }
}
});
```

However I want to show a differnt set of available times specific to the date.  for exapme my array of dates has:

2015-10-23,2015-10-24,2015-10-25

I would like 2015-10-23 to allow '17:00','17:30','18:00','18:30' times
2015-10-24 to allow '17:30','18:00'
2015-1025 to allow '17:00'

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for an answer to the same question. By trying to work out how the datetimepicker plugin works and a bit of trial and error, I've come up with the below, which seems to work for me. Hope this helps you.

Outstanding issues:

- If the user doesn't select an available time, the current time is used instead.
- The today button is useful but it allows today to be selected even if there are no available times.
- My string handling is rather clunky.

I'd welcome any refinements to the code - in the meantime, here it is:

```
  var free_slots = { // object containing all available slots
    // date        // array containing times for each date
    "2016-03-09" : ["12:00", "13:00"],
    "2016-03-16" : ["14:00", "15:00"]
  }

  function pad(n, width, z) {
    z = z || '0';
    n = n + '';
    return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
  }

  $ ("#datefield") .datetimepicker ({
    allowTimes: ['00:00'],
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(date.getMonth()+1,2) + "-" + pad(date.getDate(),2);  
      if (ymd in free_slots)
        return [true, "", "appointments available"];
      else
        return [false, "", "fully booked"];
    },
    onSelectDate: function () {
      // The below options seem to be appended to the existing datetimepicker:
      $ ("#datefield") .datetimepicker ({
        allowTimes: free_slots [$ ("#datefield") .val () .substr (0,10) .replace (/\//g, "-")],
      });
    }
  });
```